# Publish post facebook page & twitter automatically

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, facebook, twitter, social-sharing

I need a feature in wordpress, using which a new post automatically posted to Facebook Page & Twitter.

Do I need some plugin to do that.. Do you know any plugin that provides for this kind of feature? And may be support more social networks.

Comment: The [Jetpack](http://jetpack.me/support/publicize/) plugin includes this feature. Also, plugin recommendations are [off topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#closing) here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download facebook auto post plugin from following link;[Plugin Download URL here](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-page-publish/)

Follow author notes in installation and also see screenshot before installation.

download twitter auto post plugin from following link [plugin download link here](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-to-twitter/)